# Security Risk for Self Signed Certificate in WCF

Tags: wcf

Could anyone please let me know if there are any major security risk for the scenario below?

> Scenario: I've a WCF web services hosted in azure. Instead of buying a
>   third party X.509 Certificate, I would like to generate our own
>   self-signed certificate and provide my ROOT CA to the third party
>   clients. They then import the ROOT CA to their certificate store. This
>   would then enable a https with self signed certificate.

I'm quiet new to X509 Certificate and SSL etc. If anyone could let me know the PROS and CONs of this solution will be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's secure if your clients are willing to *accept* a self-signed certificate.

The main idea behind X.509 is *trust* - that is to say, when you accept a certificate as proof of identity, you're not trusting *them*, you're trusting the authority who *issued* the certificate.

In the case of self-signed certificates, the authority (issuer) and the thing it's identifying are the same thing.  Except self-signed certificates are *not* root certificates, and don't actually designate a signing authority.  That means that many policies and systems actually consider them invalid, and one must jump through several hoops and change configuration options (including those in WCF) to enable them to be used.  Your clients will be wading through a whole bunch of *DO NOT DO THIS* warnings in the process.

Self-signed certificates are mainly intended for development. They're "secure" in the sense that they do what it says on the tin, but it's like paying with a handwritten IOU note instead of a check. Is it authentic? Who knows?

If you have the time, I'd really recommend shelling out the $50 for a certificate or setting up an actual PKI if you plan to issue several of these.  The clients are less likely to laugh at you if they have competent IT staff.

Comment: If you only care about encryption, then why not use a self signed certificate. If you also need authentication, then just buy from a commercial CA.

Answer (score 0):

The only pro I can think of is it saves you a bit money. As for cons, you can't revoke a self-signed certificate, so if your certificate is compromised you're out of luck. (Not to mention it may strike some clients as unprofessional if you're not willing to properly certify your company)

Answer (score 0):

For multi-vendor scenario self signed certificate is not good idea. it is always ideal to get certificate from well known publisher. it is looks professional.